# How to get a string from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am busy making my first android app, but now I really need some help.

The concept:
I have two activities, one main screen handler and one sub screen handler activity. The main screen handler activity handles the a listview with multiple items. Each of these items have some fragments linked to it. Whenever the user clicks on an item from the listview, the specific fragments that belongs to the selected items are put in the intent from the second activity and the sub screen handler is than started. The sub screen handler receives the specific fragments that were put in the intent. These fragments are than shown to the user with the use of a viewpager.

The code (so far):

```
public class MainScreenHandler extends FragmentActivity {
    private ArrayList<SubScreenFragments> subScreenFragmentList = new ArrayList<SubScreenFragments>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_handler_layout);
        subScreenFragmentList.add(new SubScreenFragments(getString(R.string.listView_downstops),new FragmentDownstopsOverview(), new FragmentDownstopsEffects(),
                new FragmentDownstopsMeasure(), new FragmentDownstopsAdjust()));
        String[] listViewNameArray = new String[subScreenFragmentList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < listViewNameArray.length; i++) {
            listViewNameArray[i] = subScreenFragmentList.get(i).getListViewName();
        }
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listview.setClickable(true);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_row_layout, listViewNameArray);
        listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentMainScreenDialog fragmentMainScreenDialog = new FragmentMainScreenDialog();
                //Put string array, which contains the heading names from the fragments from the subScreenFragmentList, inside the bundle.
                fragmentMainScreenDialog.show(fm,"fragmentMainScreenDialog");
                return true;
            }
        });
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SubScreenHandler.class);
                Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
                myBundle.putSerializable("fragmentList", subScreenFragmentList.get(i).getFragments());
                myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

class SubScreenFragments {
    String listViewName;
    Fragment fragmentTab1, fragmentTab2, fragmentTab3, fragmentTab4;

    public SubScreenFragments(String listViewName, Fragment fragmentTab1, Fragment fragmentTab2, Fragment fragmentTab3, Fragment fragmentTab4) {
        this.listViewName = listViewName;
        this.fragmentTab1 = fragmentTab1;
        this.fragmentTab2 = fragmentTab2;
        this.fragmentTab3 = fragmentTab3;
        this.fragmentTab4 = fragmentTab4;
    }

    public String getListViewName() {
        return listViewName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Fragment> getFragments() {
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        if (fragmentTab1 != null)
            fragmentList.add(fragmentTab1);
        if (fragmentTab2 != null)
            fragmentList.add(fragmentTab2);
        if (fragmentTab3 != null)
            fragmentList.add(fragmentTab3);
        if (fragmentTab4 != null)
            fragmentList.add(fragmentTab4);
        return fragmentList;
    }
}
```

And my second acitivity:

```
public class SubScreenHandler extends FragmentActivity{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sub_screen_handler_layout);
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragmentList.addAll((ArrayList<Fragment>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fragmentList"));
        for (Object item : fragmentList) {
            if (!(item instanceof Fragment)) {
                throw new ClassCastException("List contained non-Fragment objects: " + item.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            }
        }
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); // Make sure the off screen page limit is set to 1
        UnderlinePageIndicator underlinePageIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        underlinePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        doFirstRun();
    }
    private void doFirstRun(){
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("com.example.offroad_set_up_book", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isTutorialChecked", false)){
            View view = View.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.layout.checkbox_alert_dialog,null);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkBox.setText(getString(R.string.alertDialog_checkbox_text));
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checkBoxState) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                    if(checkBoxState){
                        editor.putBoolean("isTutorialChecked", true);
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                    else{
                        editor.putBoolean("isTutorialChecked", false);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alertDialog_tutorial));
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
}

class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentList.addAll(fragments);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragmentList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

The problem:
On the main screen handler (the user sees the listview with the different selectable items) I now am implementing a long item click listener. When this listener is called a fragment dialog is opened with another listview inside it. This listview should contain a the title from each fragment from the selected item.

So I thought when I specify the string inside each fragment and make a getter inside the fragment I would be able to extract the string. This does 'work' the following way:

```
FragmentDownstopsOverview fragmentDownstopsOverview = new FragmentDownstopsOverview();
String string=fragmentDownstopsOverview.getFragmentTitle();
```

So I thought I could easily implement this in my SubScreenFragments class. This is how I tried it(note I only tried to make it work on one fragment of an SubScreenFragments object first to see if it work:

```
class SubScreenFragments {
    String listViewName;
    Fragment fragmentTab1, fragmentTab2, fragmentTab3, fragmentTab4;

    public SubScreenFragments(String listViewName, Fragment fragmentTab1, Fragment fragmentTab2, Fragment fragmentTab3, Fragment fragmentTab4) {
        this.listViewName = listViewName;
        this.fragmentTab1 = fragmentTab1;
        this.fragmentTab2 = fragmentTab2;
        this.fragmentTab3 = fragmentTab3;
        this.fragmentTab4 = fragmentTab4;
    }

    // my other code

    public String getTitle(){
        return fragmentTab1.getFragmentTitle();
    }
}
```

This didn't work of course because fragmentTab1 is an Fragment object, and not an FragmentDownstopsOverview object which does contain the specific getter (getFragmentTitle) I want to access (if I explain it right.... still new haha).

Does anybody know how I can access a getter from a fragment (like FragmentDownstopsOverview) that is passed to the SubScreenFragments class. So it would look something like this:

```
public class MainScreenHandler extends FragmentActivity{
   public void onCreate(....){
   //code
   SubScreenFragments subScreenFragments = new SubScreenFragments("Downstops", new    FragmentDownstopsOverview, null,null,null);
   String string = SubScreenFragments.getTitle();
   //code 
   }
}

class SubScreenFragments {
        String listViewName;
        Fragment fragmentTab1, fragmentTab2, fragmentTab3, fragmentTab4;

    public SubScreenFragments(String listViewName, Fragment fragmentTab1, Fragment fragmentTab2, Fragment fragmentTab3, Fragment fragmentTab4) {
        this.listViewName = listViewName;
        this.fragmentTab1 = fragmentTab1;
        this.fragmentTab2 = fragmentTab2;
        this.fragmentTab3 = fragmentTab3;
        this.fragmentTab4 = fragmentTab4;
    }

    // my other code

    public String getTitle(){
       get the title from the fragment that is put inside 'fragmentTab1' (so in this case, get
       the title (by a getter inside the fragment) from the fragment FragmentDownstopsOverview)
       and return it.
    }
}
```

**I'll hope it is clear enough what I want to achieve, otherwise I will try and explain my questions better!**

Greetings from me, a 19 year old that wants to learn android (and a lot of other different things :))

Comment: You could define a common interface that must be implemented by all of your fragments.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to implement your own Fragment, "public class MyFragment extends Fragment ..."
Then implement a setTitle and getTitle method that you can call from any instance of that fragment.

Here's a good write up on [Fragments](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_overview).

Comment: I already made my fragments as well as my setter and getter methods. This does work, however I want to acces them from the inside of the SubScreenFragments class in my code i.e. fragmentTab1.setTitle or fragmentTab1.getTitle. I know this doesn't work, but I don't know a way to make it work.

Comment: You need to use listeners to notify the activity that hosts the fragments, the activity then can get the title and send it back to whatever fragment needs it. Check the link I posted for an example of two fragments communicating through an activity.